# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed

Tags: android, runnable, illegalstateexception, android-handler, android-looper

I am trying to access some `SharedPreferences` and inflate a `Dialog` on the `mainUiThread` inside activity's `onCreate()` method:

Here is some of my `onCreate()` method code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Access shared Prefs, then inflate a dialog using the 
            // LayoutInflater class
        }
    });
}
```

**Why I did this?**
I noticed that the code I'm using to access the `SharedPreferences` then inflating a `Dialog` makes heavy load on the main Thread so I put it inside a `Handler`. I started to get this on `Crashlytics`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified message queue synchronization  barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed.
   at android.os.MessageQueue.removeSyncBarrier(MessageQueue.java:289)
   at android.os.Looper.removeSyncBarrier(Looper.java:275)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5996)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any idea?

Comment: `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` is creating `Handler` on the current thread, which is the UI thread there. That is, that whole `Handler` setup is rather pointless.

Comment: @MikeM. Any idea of how to put this on a separate thread the right way?

Comment: @pskink Would you mind posting a working example that accesses the `SharedPreferences` then showing a `Dialog`after reading some prefs values?

Comment: @blueware why don't use AsyncTask ??

Comment: Considering that you can not save too much data in `SharedPreferences` I would rather took a look into `layout` design. To keep good performance, inflation layout needs to be below 16.66 ms. Every inflation which goes above that needs attention. So either you have too much nesting inside your layout or overlapping which slows down inflation or there is another code which is heavy for main thread.